# RestFB - How to publish a post to different user's page using RestFB API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to publish a post as a user to a Page.

say I am a User A, and I want to publish a post in the Page of User B.

How do I implement it Using RestFB, can someone please help me.?

Also, am able to publish post to my page, but when I try using other page's pageToken am getting an error message `Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include a target_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> say I am a User A, and I want to publish a post in the Page of User B.

You can't do that any more via API.

It used to be possible to post to a page, so that it would show in the "visitor's posts" section - but that required `publish_actions` permission, which has been removed a while ago.

You can now only post to pages you have admin access to.

---

(Assuming by "page" you actually meant a Facebook Page - not a user profile? But posting to the latter is not possible any more via API either, not even to your own.)

Comment: Hey thanks... yea, I meant only the Facebook page not the user.,is it possible to Direct message from a User to a page using this RestFB?

Comment: No, you can not send messages on behalf of users via API either.